# Setting the Content of a Scroll View in Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: xcode

I am a beginner at using Xcode, and I am sure what I am asking is simple but I do not yet know how to do this: I want to attach display an image on a scroll view.

Details:

I am using Xcode 4.3.2 and have added a scroll view to my view controller by dragging and dropping it onto the view from the object library.

In my header file I have:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

In my implementation file I have:

```
@synthesize scrollView;
```

I have an image that is approx 420 x 1900 that I'd like to add to the scroll view. HOW DO I DO THIS? I created a UIImage view and set the image view to the image:

```
UIImage *scrollViewImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fileName.png"];
[imageView setImage:scrollViewImage];
```

but I don't know how to perform the last step of connecting the image to the scroll view so that it displays it. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `UIImageView` to the `UIScrollView`.

```
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

Have you also created the UIImageView? You do not mention how you set it up in your question.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed. Yes, I did create the UIImage View the same way I created the scroll view... I just didn't know how to connect the two together.